VBA input formula instead of the result
I am trying to input a formula with variants in a cell, but when I run the code I get formula's result in a cell, not formula itself.
Is it possible to change my code so it does what I need?
I need to check column's header in row 6, if it's value is "Forecast", multiplication formula should be placed in rows below.
(Number of sales for each day in row 9 multiplied by a value in column 39 - resulting formula inserted in every cell in my established range)
Dim ShMonth As Worksheet
Set ShMonth = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Month")

Dim c As Long
Dim r As Long
For c = 7 To 37
For r = 12 To 53
If ShMonth.Cells(6, c).Value = "Forecast" Then
ShMonth.Cells(r, c).Formula = "=" & ShMonth.Cells(9, c) & "*" & ShMonth.Cells(r, 39)
End If
Next r
Next c



VBA can apply a formula to multiple cells simultaneously, eliminating the need to loop through each row individually.
Microsoft documentation:

Range.Resize property (Excel)


Range.FormulaR1C1 property (Excel)

Sub Macro1()
    Dim ShMonth As Worksheet
    Set ShMonth = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Month")
    Dim c As Long, r As Long
    For c = 7 To 37
        If ShMonth.Cells(6, c).Value = "Forecast" Then
            ShMonth.Cells(12, c).Resize(42).FormulaR1C1 = "=R9C*RC39"
        End If
    Next c
End Sub


Hi taller, the code works, thanks a lot! So in this specific case the resize function expands active range from row 12 to 42 rows below that, right?

Yes. expression.Resize (RowSize, ColumnSize) may have two arguments. Check MS doc link in my answer.
What should I do when someone answers my question?
